# Multiple word as input in Alexa Skill

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to create an alexa skill that can take multiple words as input and can read it out to user. Here is my Intent Schema:

```js
{
  "intents": [
    {
      "intent": "AMAZON.CancelIntent"
    },
    {
      "intent": "AMAZON.StopIntent"
    },
    {
      "intent": "AMAZON.HelpIntent"
    },
    {
      "intent": "madlibIntent",
      "slots": [
        {
          "name": "STEPVALUE",
          "type": "AMAZON.LITERAL"
        },
        {
          "name": "duration",
          "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm using `AMAZON.LITERAL` to take multiple words as input from user. My sample utterances are given below:

`madlibIntent begin madlib
madlibIntent build madilb
madlibIntent {z|STEPVALUE}
madlibIntent {z z|STEPVALUE}
madlibIntent {duration}`

The problem is: it can take one word as input when uttered and can read it out. But if the user says multiple word, it can't take any word as input. For example: It can take 'nice'  as input but doesn't get 'very nice'.
Can anyone help me finding out what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! The sample utterance should be written in this form:

```
madlibIntent begin madlib
madlibIntent build madilb
madlibIntent {STEPVALUE}
madlibIntent {STEPVALUE} {STEPVALUE}
madlibIntent {STEPVALUE} {STEPVALUE} {STEPVALUE}
```

You need to build custom slot with one,two and three words instead of just using `AMAZON.LITERAL` so that it can take one, two or three words as input. If you want to take four or more words as input, just create more lines in `Sample utterances` and keep adding `{STEPVALUE}` or whatever the name of your custom intent is.